# user@ip: Permission denied (publickey).?

Tags: git, ssh

trying to push from my own self hosted git-lab server to another server,
and i'm trying to push throw CI/CD and git-lab runner

my `.gitlab-ci` is:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chown $USER ~/.ssh/config
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building..."
    - ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_SERVER "cd var/www/ && ls && exit"

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Testing..."
```

i just created a ssh key on the server that i want to push to and i added the private key to the git-lab server as git-lab variable an then used it in the script `.gitlab-ci`, but did't add any public key anywhere and I`m getting the error:

> user@ip: Permission denied (publickey).

In the build stage please any help and many thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to add the public key to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `$DEPLOY_SERVER`. Can you try this and let us know the results ?

Comment: it's worked thankssssssssss, i can accepted as answer if you want to added as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the public key to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `$DEPLOY_SERVER` which basically tells the server which public keys are authorized to access the server through ssh using the username `user`